Seek bar not working in video player developed for Tizen OS using flutter platform
Any one know why seek bar not working in video player build using flutter for tizen OS.. Three players working video fine, (flick_video_player: 0.7.0 , video_player_videohole 0.5.1, video_player_tizen 2.4.9) but seek bar not working.. please help.. thank you !
I am trying to build a video player for Samsung tizen OS TV . Three packages for player is working the video fine but in all the players the seek bar is not working. If seek bar is working only we can manually select the position in the slider to play video from a particular position.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
